# How do I align like this with VIM's Tabular Plugin?

Tags: vim, alignment, tabular

This is my code:

```
john,betty,wally,beth 
walter,george,thomas,john
herbert,bob,petty,mick`
```

Does anyone know how to align it to this with VIM's Tabular Plugin:

```
john,    betty,  wally,  beth
walter,  george, thomas, john
herbert, bob,    petty,  mick
```

I know how to do this in Align Plugin but can't find out how it works in Tabular.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Tabularize /,\zs
```

See `:help \zs`

Since the previous pattern doesn't work, try with this:

```
Tabularize /[^,]\+,
```

Comment: your solution (the one I tried also) removes the first characters of the second and third column.

Comment: Right, I can reproduce that and looks like a bug. I have created a ticket for this: https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular/issues/3

Comment: It doesn't exactly looks like a bug maybe… check my answer — too much text to fit here

Comment: I _does_ look like a bug, tabular should not remove text from the buffer.

Answer (score 14):

I'm not a master in this, and everything I'll say here is based on **my** understanding of Tabularize.

Tabularize always splits things in fields, described by the regex. For example:

```
abc,d,e
a,b,cde

:Tab /,
```

Causes it to divide each line like the following:

```
|abc|,|d|,|e|
|a|,|b|,|cde|
```

Then each field is padded with spaces so the delimiter field align — and everything receives and extra-space by default (except for the last field, I think).

```
|abc |, |d |, |e  |
|a   |, |b |, |cde|
```

Resulting in:

```
abc , d , e
a   , b , cde
```

By adding flags, you can control alignment and padding for each field. If you provide less flags than needed, they are reused. So, to make everything align the same way, say left with padding 0 you can use a single flag that will be repeated for every field. So:

```
abc,d,e
a,b,cde

Tab /,/l0 <-- or c0, or r0 or whatever

abc,d,e
a  ,b,cde
```

The conclusion I have I my mind is that there isn't much sense in having a zero width field (like `:Tab /,\zs`), probably causing it to get the first character after the pattern and messing up, cutting it.

Now, for me `:Tab /[^,]\+,` didn't worked properly, generating doubled spaces:

```
john,     betty,   wally,  beth
walter,   george,  thomas, john
herbert,  bob,     petty,  mick`
        ^^       ^^
```

I think that's because there is no intermediate field. This pattern, makes a field delimiter reside side by side with another one, like this:

```
|john,||betty,||wally,||beth|
```

Then the zero with field generated (between delimiters) is also padded with the extra 1 space by default.

```
|john, | |betty, | |wally, ||beth| <-- for some outrageous reason the las one is cut.

john,  betty,  wally, beth
```

**How to solve it?**

I'd open space for a delimiter, that doesn't cause a delimiter to be near others. How? Simply adding a space after the comma.

```
john,betty,wally,beth 
walter,george,thomas,john
herbert,bob,petty,mick`

:%s/,/, /g

john, betty, wally, beth 
walter, george, thomas, john
herbert, bob, petty, mick`
```

Now you can align everything on spaces and zero padding:

```
john, betty, wally, beth 
walter, george, thomas, john
herbert, bob, petty, mick`

:Tab / /l0

john,    betty,  wally,  beth
walter,  george, thomas, john
herbert, bob,    petty,  mick`
```

I hope that helps understanding Tabularize!

Comment: great explication! Thank you very much.

Comment: found a problem: it aligns at every space and not only after every space after a ","  --> john, betty davis, wally, beth will align also between betty and davis.

Comment: Try with `:Tabularize /,\zs \+/`

Comment: @Remonn, That's it (Thanks @El Isra!). I didn't include it on the text assuming there would be no extra spaces, but the this last regex solves the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Building on Raimondi's answer,

```
:Tabularize /,\zs/l0r1
```

makes more sense to me and it's also in just one command :-).

The `l0r1` means left-align with 0 space in the left padding and 1 space in the right padding.

Answer (score 1):

Another option may be to cheat and use the names also as a part of the delimiter:

```
:Tabularize /[a-z]*,/l0l1
```

Which looks for any name in lowercase with a comma. Everything is aligned left and at least one space follows on the delimited comma.

Answer (score 1):

I have something similar I'm doing. I regularly need to turn comma-delimited values into columns:

```
a, b
a,b,c
a, b, c
a, b, c
ab,cd,ef
ab, cd,ef
ab,cd
ab, cd

john, betty davis, wally, beth 
walter, george, thomas, john
herbert, bob, petty, mick
```

Using `:s/,\s*/, /g` preps the values to add a single space after the commas:

```
a, b
a, b, c
a, b, c
a, b, c
ab, cd, ef
ab, cd, ef
ab, cd
ab, cd

john, betty davis, wally, beth 
walter, george, thomas, john
herbert, bob, petty, mick
```

Running `:Tab /,\zs \+/10` turns them into:

```
a,  b
a,  b,  c
a,  b,  c
a,  b,  c
ab, cd, ef
ab, cd, ef
ab, cd
ab, cd

john,    betty davis, wally,  beth
walter,  george,      thomas, john
herbert, bob,         petty,  mick
```

Now I just need to figure out how to turn them into a `vmap` that works.

Answer (score -1):

And how about this:

```
%s/,/,\t/g
```